# Best way to exclude 0,0 from geography results (PostGIS, GeoDjango)

Tags: postgis, geodjango

Using PostGis and GeoDjango with a model having a Geography field I'm trying to exclude results where the location is 0,0. I get the error `PostGIS geography does not support the "exact" lookup.` The only thing I can think to do is exclude points that are 0 meters from 0,0:

```
.exclude(location__distance_lte=(Point(0, 0), D(m=1)))
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
.exclude(location__intersects=Point(0, 0))
```

The `intersects` spatial lookup is one of the four available on geography column types in GeoDjango.

In PostGIS, `ST_Intersects` natively supports geography column types and has a tolerance of about 0.00001 metres.

More info:

- http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersects.html
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#intersects